# Showing that these vectors are linearly dependent - Have I done enough?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

In $\mathbb R^3$, let $$ v_1 =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
 $$ v_2 =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        -2\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ v_3 =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ v_4 =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Show that they are linearly dependent in $\mathbb R^3$

**Attempt**

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \in \mathbb R$ such that $ a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 +  a_4 v_4 = \mathbf 0 $

When I expand on this I get the following system of equations:

$$a_1 + a_4 = 0$$
$$a_1 - a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 0$$
$$2a_1 - 2a_2 + 3a_3 + a_4 = 0$$

Ultimately, I get  the following answers:

$$ a_1 = -a_2 = -a_3 = -a_4$$

i.e.

$$ a_1
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        -1 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 \\
        a_2\\
        a_3\\
        a_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is this enough? How do I conclude from here that this is linearly dependent? I mean obviously $a_1 \ne 0$ (well in at least one instance) - but how do I show that further? Help would be awesome.

Comment: yeah it is enough, you have found constants $a_1,\cdots,a_4$ which are not all zero and yet $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_4v_4=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either argue that since $\;\dim_{\Bbb R}\Bbb R^3=3\;$ then the maximal number of lin. ind. vectors is three and thus your four vectors **must** be lin. dependent, or else do what you did and observe tha the condition $\,a_1=-a_2=-a_3=-a_4\;$ does **not** force all the coefficients to be zero and thus there are non-zero coeff. s.t. $\;a_1v_1+\ldots+a_4v_4=0\;$ and by definition this means the vectors are l.i.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a simple way to show this. Consider the matrix with columns the vectors you mentioned.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &  1\\
 1& -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2& -2 &3  & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$               and try to find non-zero solutions in $\mathbb{R^{4}}\,$ to the

system $Ax=0$. If there is a non-zero solution then the column vectors

are linearly dependent!!